# SQL Server - Grouping a field correctly

Tags: sql-server

Im running the query

SELECT

```
    YEAR(TL_SYS_DATE)               AS [YEAR]
    ,MONTH(TL_SYS_DATE)             AS [MONTH]
    ,NEW_PRODUCT_NAME               AS [PRODUCT]
    ,COMP_PDT_CODE                  AS PROD_CODE
    ,NEW_CONTRACT_NO
    ,NEW_STATUS
    ,PREMIUM_AMT

    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TERM_LENGTH = '10 Year' AND NEW_STATUS IN ('Active/Restrict','Active') THEN
            NEW_CONTRACT_NO 
    END)                                            AS [10 YR CONTRACTS]


    ,SUM(CASE WHEN TERM_LENGTH = '10 Year' AND NEW_STATUS IN ('Active/Restrict','Active') THEN
            PREMIUM_AMT
    END)                                            AS [10 YR Premium]

    ,SUM(CASE WHEN NEW_STATUS IN ('Surr/Freelook', 'Terminated/Surr','Withdrawn') THEN
            SURRENDER_VALUE
    END)                                            AS [Surr/Term/Withdrawn Amount]     

    ,SUM(CASE WHEN NEW_STATUS NOT IN ('Surr/Freelook', 'Terminated/Surr','Withdrawn') THEN
            ACCOUNT_VALUE
    END)                                            AS [ACCOUNT VALUE]

    -- NEW_STATUS NOT IN ('Surr/Freelook', 'Terminated/Surr','Withdrawn') AND TERM_LENGTH != '10 Year'

    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN UPPER(NEW_STATUS) = 'CLAIM' THEN
            NEW_CONTRACT_NO 
    END)                                            AS [Death Claim Contracts]

FROM
    DB1
    where YEAR(TL_SYS_DATE) = '2014'
    and MONTH(TL_SYS_DATE) = '4'
    AND PREMIUM_AMT > 0
GROUP BY
    YEAR(TL_SYS_DATE)
    ,MONTH(TL_SYS_DATE)
    ,NEW_PRODUCT_NAME
    ,ACCOUNT_VALUE      
    ,COMP_PDT_CODE
    ,NEW_CONTRACT_NO
    ,NEW_STATUS
    ,PREMIUM_AMT
```

which is resulting in

[image: Result 1]

What i would like to do is sum the PREMIUM_AMT but not the ACCOUNT_VALUE

So for contract 6880000153 it would be PREMIUM_AMT = 110500.00 AND ACCOUNT VALUE 105306.07 All on one row.

Comment: so put sum(PREMIUM_AMT) and remove PREMIUM_AMT from the group by?

Comment: That triples the account value field also.

Comment: Since I don't have any tables or data to work with I was guessing. If you want help we need something to work with. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your results in a CTE and aggregate from there

```
WITH CTE_Example
AS
(
your query
)
SELECT MAX(YEAR),
       MAX(MONTH),
       NEW_CONTRACT_NO,
       MAX(NEW_STATUS),
       SUM(PREMIUM_AMT),
       MAX([ACCOUNT VALUE]),
       MAX([Death Claim Contracts])
FROM CTE_Example
GROUP BY NEW_CONTRACT_NO
```

So some disclaimers, this will aggregate and yield the results you want. But I would be really skeptical of using MAX(NEW_STATUS) without knowing your whole data scheme. Because if 6880000153 had a combination of Claim and Suspended, it would always yield Suspended because it is alphabetically greater and that may not be what you need. Also I didn't put the column [10 YR Premium] and [Surr/Term/Withdrawn Amount] in because they are NULL. But feel free to add them in and aggregate appropriately.